# Why are there no notifications for chat messages?

Tags: discussion, support

Why are there no notifications for new chat messages? Or do I only get notifications when I stay in a chat room? If so, why do I leave a chat room automatically when I navigate away from the chat room site?

Comment: There are. But only after a while (20 minutes) and if we can see you have not seen them. They are not realtime.